# Word for the phenomenon/ideology of absolutely obeying parents' orders?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

In some cultures, morally parents have dominant power over their children, even after they have grown up.

What is the word for this phenomenon/ideology?

Comment: *filial duty*, *filial respect*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noun: [*filial duty*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=filial+duty) or [*filial respect*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=filial).

Duty of a child to its parents

Derived forms: filial duties

Type of: duty, obligation, responsibility

-- WordWeb Online

Comment: Also (especially in China/Confucianism) [***filial piety***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filial_piety).

Answer (score 0):

Obedient?

> adjective: obedient
>
> > complying or willing to comply with orders or requests; submissive to another's will.
> >     *"she was totally obedient to him"*
>
> **synonyms**:
>   compliant, acquiescent, tractable, amenable;
>   dutiful, good, law-abiding, deferential, respectful, duteous, well trained, well disciplined, manageable, governable;
>   docile, tame, biddable, meek, passive, submissive, unresisting, yielding;
>   malleable, pliable, pliant, subservient, obsequious, servile;
>   Stepford
>   *"obviously, you want an obedient dog for security work"*
>   **antonyms**:   disobedient, rebellious

Answer (score -1):

How about *brainwashing*?

Dictionary.com:

> [*brainwashing*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/brainwashing?s=t): any method of controlled systematic indoctrination, especially one based
>   on repetition or confusion

Many children are *brainwashed* by their parents ... and never escape from it. I call the result "baggage" -- being loaded up with someone else's beliefs rather than one's own. To be free, one must get rid one's self of one's baggage ... overcome one's *brainwashing*.